How to automatically find the boundary points (not just vertices) of a 2d point cloud or convex set?
I have a 2d point cloud of shape [1000,2]; which means I have 1000 points in the XY plane or 1000 (x,y) points in a plane. Now I need to find out all the boundary points, or all the points that lie on the convex hull of this points set. I am wondering is there any package or algorithm that will be helpful for my case.
Thanks in advance!
I tried using the convex hull algorithm, but it is giving me only the vertices, but not other points that fall within the vertices. I am actually searching for some algorithm that is applicable to all convex sets in a 2d plane. Thanks

It sounds like a Graham scan will achieve this
I'm not sure which tech stack you're using, but there are a few language implementations for reference here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/convex-hull-using-graham-scan/
If that worked for you, please mark answer as accepted, thanks

Seems like Convex hull using the Graham Scan is providing only the "vertices of the convex set" or simply "convex hull". Suppose, I have generated 2d points of shape rectangle to check my task. The mentioned algorithm only provides the convex hull or 4 corner points or 4 vertices of the rectangle. However, I am looking for some algorithm that can find not only the vertices rather all the boundary points (vertices + boundary points on the line connecting two vertices if there are any). Interestingly, in case of a "circle", all vertices are the boundary points.
